# SQL Server 2008 R2 Restore Database From File - "failed: 38(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)"

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm running a database restore on a backup file that was created up on a clients server, the backup file has been moved to our server (same SQL version 2008 R2) and I'm getting the following error after the T-SQL has been running for nearly 7 minutes:

TSQL:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [Charms_OrangeGrove]   
FROM    DISK = N'S:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Charms_OrangeGrove_290114.bak'   
    WITH  MOVE N'CharmsData_dat'   
          TO N'S:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Charms_OrangeGrove.mdf',    
          MOVE N'CharmsData_log' 
          TO N'S:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Charms_OrangeGrove_Log.ldf'
```

Error:

```
Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Read on "S:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Charms_OrangeGrove_290114.bak" 
    failed: 38(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are having a disk read problem or perhaps a corrupted backup.

I would try

```
a. Run RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK =  
        N'S:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Charms_OrangeGrove_290114.bak'
b. If it comes up clean try copying it to a different location 
        (preferably a different drive on different physical hardware)
```

Here is a link where someone had a similar problem.  It has some additional steps he tried and mentions that he had a hardware problem.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2a127a18-dfd0-4668-afc4-f5eb497f4977/sql-server-2008-restore-fails-msg-3203?forum=sqldisasterrecovery

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried the VERIFYONLY method but received an almost identical error message.
I'm going to backup the database again and try with another file.

Comment: Your backup was probably corrupt then.  Either that or the location has problems.  If your next backup has problems as well I would have the location checked.

Comment: The new backup worked straightaway! 
Strange that the SQL Server I used to create the first backup didn't report an issue initially? 
Ah well, problem solved anyway thanks.

Comment: It's generally suggested that you test your backups if not every time then at least occasionally.  Because of IO problems you will occasionally (hopefully not to often) get backups that are corrupt and unusable.

Comment: In my case the file was downloaded from a cloud backup service, a 30GB sql server backup. Corrupetd file!